# Prevent <cite> tag appearing within RSS Feed

Tags: xslt, coldfusion, rss

Im using doctype: XHTML Mobile Profile 1.2, XML version="1.0 and Content-Type "application/xhtml+xml"

Is it possible to disable or prevent `<cite>` tag appearing within RSS feed, Due to the fact that I keep getting this error on the Page itself.

```
error on line 24 at column 70: expected '>'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I am using an external feed from another site, which is not mine to control or edit.

I am using an XSLT and ColdFusion file to read the external RSS file, and display it the way I want within my XSLT, I already have in place `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to prevent lose code showing up within the feed. My XSLT works when this  tag is not there

I have tried to get around it, but no luck. Is it actually possible to do this?

CFM

```
<cfcontent type="application/xhtml+xml" reset="yes">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">

<cfhttp method="Get" url="http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/rss.xml">
<cfset xmlInput = CFHTTP.FileContent>
<cfset MyXslFile = Expandpath("animenewsrss.xsl")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xslInput" file="#MyXslFile#">
<cfset xmlOutput = XMLTransform(xmlInput, xslInput)>
<cfoutput>#xmloutput#</cfoutput>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="rss/channel">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="head">
     <xsl:element name="title">Anime News</xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="body">
      <xsl:element name="div"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="'hstyle'"/></xsl:attribute>Media Events UK - Anime News</xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="div"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="'nstyle'"/>
        </xsl:attribute><xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">index.cfm</xsl:attribute>Home</xsl:element> - 
        <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">listings.cfm</xsl:attribute>Listings</xsl:element> - 
        <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">venue.cfm</xsl:attribute>Venues</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() &lt; 6]" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[position() &lt; 6]">
  <div class="rsstyle">
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:value-of select="pubDate" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(description, 1, 50), '...')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:element>
</div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If your XSLT works without <cite> it would be especially useful if you could show your XSLT stylesheet. Seems like your XSLT and CF produce XML that is not well-formed.

Comment: @MathiasMüller My whole project it well formed, its this page when the external site uses <cite> tags in their RSS, then it comes up with an error

Comment: I understood this perfectly well. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this line

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(description, 1, 50), '...')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

you cut the content of `<description>`, which contains `cite` elements in some cases. This leads to lines like the following in your result `HTML`:

```
<div><cite>Ni No Kuni</cite>, <cite>Tales of Xillia</ci...</div>
```

As you can see, the `cite` element is not closed properly anymore, because you cut the content of the `description` element at 50 characters. If you counted the characters, you'd notice that the content of `description` stops at 50, then "..." is inserted.

If you describe your intent behind applying substring to `decription` elements, SO can help you find a good alternative to this.

My guess is that you need to take into account the possibility that `description` contains not only text, but also *elements* (like `cite`). Then, it makes sense to use substring only on the text content of description, like this:

```
concat(substring(description/text(),1,50),'...')
```

Then go on to catch the child elements of `description`, e.g. in a separate template:

```
<xsl:template match="cite[parent::description]">
  <!--Deal with cite elements-->
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**: I adapted your stylesheet to process `cite` elements as children of `description`. There are 2 additional templates that process text nodes and `cite` nodes, both being children of `description`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="rss/channel">
  <!--I left this template unchanged!-->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[position() &lt; 6]">
  <div class="rsstyle">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:value-of select="pubDate" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="description">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[parent::description]">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cite[parent::description]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ow I see what you mean, thanks for that. I get the first part now if I allow more characters, but this might not always work for a future proof.

In the last part you talk about catch the child element of description, how would I go about making this work from your exmaple

Comment: Before I can help you any further, you really need to explain why you apply `substring` to the description element in the first place. Also, include an example of a `description` element from the _input_ RSS.

Comment: ok by using substring, it returns the substring of the first argument starting at the position specified by description, length specified by 1, characters specified by 100 now (I changed it)

Comment: example: <div><cite>Ni No Kuni</cite>, <cite>Tales of Xillia</cite>, <cite>Final Fantasy XIV</cite> nominated for ...</div>

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I know how `substring` works. I was asking **why** you apply it on description elements.

Comment: Actually you know what I have been fiddling with it, I took substring out and it works better. I put it in originally becuase it was the way I was taught in university

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to have a look at my edited answer anyway which displays the text content of cite elements as well (which your solution does not if you only remove the substring instruction).